# pydrive: how do I rename the title of a google spreadsheet once I know the id?

Tags: python, gspread, pydrive

[Here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/filemanagement.html)  under 
"Update file metadata" it shows how to change the title from a created file. I'm looking for how to change the title if I know the id or key. Or is there a way to do it in `gspread`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found it

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
a=drive.auth.service.files().get(fileId=id).execute()
a['title']="new title"
update=drive.auth.service.files().update(fileId=id,body=a).execute()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this directly with PyDrive.  CreateFile() only creates a local Python object to represent the state of a new or existing file

```
# CreateFile() can be called with an existing id.
file1 = drive.CreateFile({'id': 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'})

file1['title'] = '<new title>' # Change title.
file1.Upload()                 # Upload new title.
```

Comment: Ok. You want to rename an existing file, one for which you have only the id. If this is correct, then the above code will do /exactly/ the same as your code, just in a consistent way, using PyDrive. CreateFile() only creates a local Python object to represent the state of a new or existing file.

If you call FetchMetadata() after `file1 = ...` then you can also extract the current name.